# How to get accurate window information (dimensions, etc.) in Linux (X)?

Tags: python, linux, xserver

How can I get accurate window information in Linux? I know that I can use `wmctrl` to get a window's size, but the actual size of the window can vary due to window decorations. I need the following information and methods:

- precise window dimensions
- precise available screen space (excluding panels like gnome-panel)
- the ability to set a window to be a certain size, including decorations

What would be the best way to do this? I am interested in working with Python so something with a python module would be preferred.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What windowing library are using?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you are asking, @Mark. I am using Ubuntu 10.04 with the Gnome desktop environment and Metacity as my window manager.

Comment: I think Mark was assuming you were doing this from within the program that creates the window. Do you want this to be a tool that you run separately from the window's owner? I think you may have more luck on Superuser (http://superuser.com/).

Comment: @Nathon: yes, I want this to be a tool that can be run separately from the window's owner. Thanks for the advice, I'll ask my qustion on superuser.

Comment: @Nathon - actually, if he wants to do this from a little python script, this is suitable for SO. This question should then focus on the python approach, and the command approach is handled [there](http://superuser.com/questions/164047/how-to-get-accurate-window-information-dimensions-etc-in-linux-x).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is cross-posted to another site. http://superuser.com/q/164047

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to use X11/xlib directly (Documentation: http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/ )

Beginning from the Root you can walk through a tree via XQueryTree() and get the window Attributes via XGetWindowAttributes () / XGetGeometry ().

Ok, this is a C-Library, but there is also a Python Port: http://python-xlib.sourceforge.net/?page=documentation

Comment: How would X11 know the size of the window decorations?

Comment: Because the windows are organised in an Tree, and if you substract the size of an child window from its parent window you get the size of the decorations. Often things like close-buttons in the decoration are also X11-Windows.

`Root-Window (your Desktop) - Top-Level-Window (window with Deco) - Child windows (may be part of the decoration or content area etc.) - Buttons etc`

This approach does not work always, e.g. when Compiz is on, Compiz paints the window decoration circumventing X11 (but I am not sure on that)

Comment: But you can try an easy dump-testprogram and figure out in which part of the window hirarchy you are interested in. You can even grab its contents via XGetImage().